# Why maven insists on downloading from repo1.maven repoistory?

Tags: maven-2, maven, pom.xml

i added a private repo in my pom file, so maven should only download from it and if a dependency not found on it, build error should occur, right ?
but what happens is that sometimes i see maven downloading from repo1.maven no idea why ?
i searched in pom file about this URL but couldn't find it ?
please explain to me why or when it's downloading from repo1.maven,because i want to force it to download only from this private repo.
i am using maven 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The repository is defined in the ["Super POM"](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Super_POM), which all Maven projects inherit from.

If you wish to avoid using it, you have two alternatives:

1. Define a `repository` and a `pluginRepository` in your POM both with an `id` of `central`. This will override the super POM with the new location. The new location will still need to contain the plugins and artifacts that Maven needs, which are typically proxied from the central repository.
2. Define a `mirror` in the `settings.xml` file that has a `mirrorOf` value of either `central` or `*` (which mirrors any defined repository to a single location). This is typically used to redirect requests to a repository manager specific to your environment without changing the overall settings of a project for other users.

If you are looking for more fine-grained control, consider setting up a repository manager such as Archiva, Artifactory or Nexus that can selectively obtain artifacts from other repositories and that your builds can all use exclusively.

Answer (score 1):

The Maven [download](http://maven.apache.org/download.html) is just a bootstrap. Depending on the goals which you invoke (either from the command-line, or configured in your POM), Maven will download the necessary plug-ins to get the job done. In summary Maven cannot run without Maven Central or a proxy to Maven central.